# password validation with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a Regex for password validation which match

eg.

> abcdABCD1234$%^

password must contains atleast two lowercase,two uppercase, two numeric and two special character. But they can give more than this criteria

Note- pattern should be inorder.

```
String pattern="(?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})(?=.*[@#$%&]{2,})";
```

it is working for me but it is not checking order
means 
AB uppercase or anycharacter should not come before ab (lowercase).

Does it clear for u.

```
     String minNum="4";
     String max="20";

     String REGEX="(^(?!.*(d))(?=.*[a-z]{3,})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{3,})(?=.[@#$%&*><?+]{2,})^(?!.*(#r)).{"+minNum+","+max+"})";
     //String regex="(?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})(?=.*[@#$%&]{2,})";

      String INPUT ="acABC1333323@#";

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

   Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);

   System.out.println(m.matches());
```

it is working correctly but when i am changing password 
"ABac1333323@#"; it also matches but it is in correct according to my requirement, because AB is first order.

Comment: `But they can give more than this criteria` how can we predict your future requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
(?=[a-z]{2,}).{2,}(?=[A-Z]{2,}).{2,}(?=\d{2,}).{2,}(?=[@#$%&]{2,}).{2,}
```

It **matches** `abcdABCD1234$%^` and `abABcdCD1234$%^`

It **does not match** `ABababcdCD1234$%^` or `ABac1333323@#`

For **two or more lower case followed by two or more upper case followed by two or more digits followed by two or more special characters**, use :

```
[a-z]{2,}[A-Z]{2,}\d{2,}[@#$%&]{2,}
```

Comment: @SHAKILDANISH didn't it work?if it's working, pls accept the answer.

Comment: @NaveedS, it accepts `^` only accidentally, it will also acccept the passwords "aa234134BB45$%" or "abcdABCD1234$%Foobar", you can have any characters after each two first characters.

Comment: @SHAKILDANISH so your requirement is **two or more lower case followed by two or more upper case followed by two or more digits followed by two or more special characters**, right?

Comment: I allready got answer. but i tried this one it is also working thanks

Answer (score 3):

**To require the characters to be in a special order is the weirdest password requirement I have ever heard and I can not believe that your customer really wants this.**

Stated this I can explain your regex to you.

The [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (the `(?=...)` stuff), you are using in your regex, are normally used, when the required characters can be in any order. If you really don't have this requirement, then your regex is simple, you just need to skip your lookaheads.

**This will match your requirements:**

```
String pattern="[a-z]{2,}[A-Z]{2,}[0-9]{2,}[@#$%&]{2,}";
```

Just in case you want to allow all letters, digits and all other characters in your passwords, use Unicode code properties:

```
String pattern="p{Ll}{2,}p{Lu}{2,}\d{2,}[^\p{L}\d]{2,}";
```

Comment: thanks it is working for me.can u explain once more about lookhead and how it is working

Comment: There is a link in my answer, that explains lookahead assertions better, than I would be able to.

Comment: @stema but it will not match `abcdABCD1234$%^`

Comment: @NaveedS, yes but only because `^` is not part of the last character class.

Comment: @stema I think characters not mentioned here should also be allowed.

Comment: @NaveedS, These requirements are so weird, that I don't think so. But If yes, then `p{Ll}{2,}p{Lu}{2,}\d{2,}[^\p{L}\d]{2,}` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help you:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PwdValidator{

      private Matcher match;
      private Pattern pattern;
      private static final String PWD_PATTERN = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})";

      public PwdValidator(){
          pattern = Pattern.compile(PWD_PATTERN);
      }


      public boolean validate(final String pwd){
          match = pattern.matcher(pwd);
          return match.matches();
      }
}
```